# Malicious code running AccessController.doPrivileged

Tags: java, security

I'm new to java security; have a basic question.

My current understanding is that:

- Whenever you need to restrict what untrusted code can do, one of the ways you can accomplish this, is through the use of a custom Security policy, and running the untrusted code in a `Subject.doAsPrivileged` block.
- If the untrusted code needs to call a piece of code that DOES need some elevated permissions (such as file access, etc), you can accomplish this through the use of `AccessController.doPrivileged`.

My question is:
What stops a malicious code from inserting `AccessController.doPrivileged` calls itself ?

For example, in my case:

- I'm running user-defined Groovy scripts in a sandboxed environment; I have a very restrictive policy in place that denies most of the stuff that Groovy can do.
- I however, allow these scripts to perform certain actions that require elevated privileges (by sending an object to the groovy scripts and saying "hey, whenever you need something, just invoke this method on this object").
- The code that needs elevated privileges is running via an `AccessController.doPrivileged` statement.

So what stops the Groovy script from running a piece of code that says `AccessController.doPrivileged ( some_malicious_code )` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't get it right, using `AccessController.doPrivileged` doesn't indicate to the JVM:

> hey don't check what I'm doing you can trust me, I'm a nice guy!

It only indicates to the JVM that he doesn't need to check that the rest of the call stack has sufficient rights.

Let met give you an example, let's say that I have a Class `A` which calls a third party library `Foo` which executes some code that requires some privileges.

By default without using `AccessController.doPrivileged` when I call `Foo`, the JVM will check that the full call stack has sufficient rights so here in my policy file I need to provide the required privileges to my class `A` but also to my third party library `Foo`.

If in my Class `A`, I wrap the call to the third party library `Foo` in a `AccessController.doPrivileged`, I have no need to provide the rights to the third party library `Foo` anymore only `A` still needs them.

> So what stops the Groovy script from running a piece of code that says
>   `AccessController.doPrivileged ( some_malicious_code )` ?

If your groovy code doesn't have the required privileges to execute the malicious code, it won't be able to execute the code even if it uses  `AccessController.doPrivileged` to call it for the reason described previously.

Answer (score 0):

How malicious code is stopped from effectively calling `AccessController.doPrivileged` depends on what you mean by *code*.

If the code is **compiled bytecode**, then one of the things the container needs to do is to assign it restricted privileges when code loading. Permission checks in `AccessController.doPrivileged` go back as far as including the caller of that method, so we are okay.

If we have an **interpreter**, then we have more fun. Interpreters should lower permissions before calling random methods. One of the methods interpreters have to explicitly guard against is `doPrivileged`. Definition of *interpreter* is quite wide here. Any dodgy use of reflection with directions from untrusted source will do.

I am unfamiliar with the implementation of Groovy, so can't comment on how it handles this, or even whether it bothers at all.